# VSCode devcontainer.json mounts not working

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

Assuming I must be doing something wrong here, but I cannot seem to get VSCode to mount anything into the container with my very simple devcontainer.json file.

It currently looks as follows:

```json
{
    "name": "Terraform",
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
    "mounts": ["source=/home/paul,target=/host,type=bind,consistency=cached"]
}
```

I have also tried the example given in the docs:

```
["source=${localEnv:HOME}${localEnv:USERPROFILE},target=/host-home-folder,type=bind,consistency=cached"]
```

Neither seem to mount anything inside the container, and looking at the output of the "Dev Containers" console output, it doesn't even look like VSCode attempts to mount it. Do I need to switch something on for this to work?

Running VSCode 1.36.1 on Linux Mint. Docker CE 19.03.

Comment: I've just found that in WSL, in some cases `-v` works where `--mount` does not. In particular, `--mount source=/run/docker.sock,target=/run/docker.sock,type=bind` creates an empty undreadable directory, but `-v /run/docker.sock:/run/docker.sock` mounts the socket as expected. Unfortunately that means using `runArgs` instead of `mounts` at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

For me it worked the *workspaceMount* instead of mount

```
"workspaceMount": "source=${localWorkspaceFolder}/sub-folder,target=/workspace,type=bind,consistency=delegated",
"workspaceFolder": "/workspace"
```

as stated in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced

Answer (score 4):

## Docker-in-Docker

### Using `docker-compose`

When working with a **Docker-in-Docker** setup which utilizes the `docker-compose` functionality, the VSCode internal variable `${localWorkspaceFolder}` can be used to get the actual path to the workspace on disk. This is needed because in a Docker-in-Docker environment, "normal" paths may not work as the first Docker instance is already running in a mounted environment.

In order to make those internal VSCode variables also accessible in the `docker-compose.yaml`, you first need to define an [environment variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced#_adding-environment-variables) in your `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "DevContainer",
  "dockerFile": "Dockerfile", // this is a reference to the .devcontainer/Dockerfile, which is used by VSCode to build the DevContainer. This has nothing to do with the Dockerfile or docker-compose.yaml file your project is using.

  "remoteEnv": {
    // the original host directory which is needed for volume 
    // mount commands from inside the container (Docker in Docker)
    "HOST_PROJECT_PATH": "${localWorkspaceFolder}"
  }
}
```

Then, use the environment variable in your project's actual `./docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
services:
  webserver:
    image: nginx:mainline-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
       -  ${HOST_PROJECT_PATH}/webserver:/etc/nginx/conf.d
       -  ${HOST_PROJECT_PATH}/build:/var/www/html
```

VSCode provides even more internal variables which can be used for advanced setup and configuration of the DevContainer environment. Please have a look [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference).

### Using `Dockerfile`

More information on how to use Docker-in-Docker with Dockerfiles can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/master/containers/docker-from-docker#using-bind-mounts-when-working-with-docker-inside-the-container).

Comment: Can you elaborate this more? Your header says it's for compose, but the devcontainer definition you gave shows `dockerFile` being used.  When in the compose environment, the variable I'm creating in `remoteEnv` doesn't get set in a way that it gets found by compose.  In fact I get warnings to that effect in the devcontainer log that the variable isn't actually set.  I'm using VSCode 1.52.1.

Comment: Using devcontainer.json remoteEnv variables in docker-compose.yaml volume entries is not possible...

Comment: @Thomas my answer is for a Docker-in-Docker setup. So not only the the actual application runs inside a Docker container but also VSCode itself. The `dockerFile` variable in `.devcontainer.json` is a reference to the Dockerfile which is used by VSCode itself to start the devContainer. It has therefore nothing to do with the `docker-compose` file (or normal Dockerfile) which is used by the actual application. Furthermore, the `remoteEnv` variable is used by VSCode Docker container (the DevContainer) to provide data to other Docker containers (the application's actual container).

Comment: @polmabri when VSCode is running in the corresponding DevContainer (make sure to use the command "Remote-Containers: Open Folder in Container..."), then all the variables defined in `remoteEnv` are pushed to the environment variables which can then be used normally by the `docker-compose` functionality.

Comment: @winklerrr you're right - i misunderstood the interaction between your devcontainer.json and the docker-compose.yaml. thx for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using a prebuilt image and avoiding the rebuild option described in notification (I tought it was referring to a full Dockerfile rebuild).

After changing the `devcontainer.json` with your (mount) config take care to click the rebuild button.

[image: rebuild image option]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'll need to VSCode 1.41+ for the mounts property to work.

[Advanced containers: Add another local file mount](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/add-local-file-mount)